# While creation of excel file from suitescript ,how to border each cells?

Tags: excel, suitescript

var xmlStr = '';

```
  xmlStr += '<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" ';

  xmlStr += 'xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" ';

  xmlStr += 'xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" ';

  xmlStr += 'xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" ';

  xmlStr += 'xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">';

 

  xmlStr += '<Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">';

  xmlStr += "<Table>";

  xmlStr += "<Row>";
  

  xmlStr += '<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Client Name</Data></Cell>';
  xmlStr += '<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Entity</Data></Cell>';
  xmlStr += '<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Payment Terms</Data></Cell>';
  xmlStr += '<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">AR - Overdue</Data></Cell>';
  xmlStr += '<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Unapplied</Data></Cell>';
  xmlStr += '<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Net Overdue</Data></Cell>';
  xmlStr += '<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">%</Data></Cell>';
  xmlStr += '<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Country</Data></Cell>';
  xmlStr += "</Row>";
```

I tried different ways of styling the cells it won't work.Expecting to have excel table having bordered rows and columns wise.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with different styles and this works.

Use this style

```
xmlStr += "<Styles>";
  xmlStr += '<Style ss:ID="cellWithBorders">';
  xmlStr += "<Borders>";
  xmlStr += '<Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>';
  xmlStr += '<Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>';
  xmlStr += '<Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>';
  xmlStr += '<Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>';
  xmlStr += "</Borders>";
  xmlStr += "</Style>";
  xmlStr += "</Styles>";




full code you can use below reference ,
```

var xmlStr = '';

```
  xmlStr += '<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" ';

  xmlStr += 'xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" ';

  xmlStr += 'xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" ';

  xmlStr += 'xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" ';

  xmlStr += 'xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">';

  xmlStr += "<Styles>";
  xmlStr += '<Style ss:ID="cellWithBorders">';
  xmlStr += "<Borders>";
  xmlStr += '<Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>';
  xmlStr += '<Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>';
  xmlStr += '<Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>';
  xmlStr += '<Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>';
  xmlStr += "</Borders>";
  xmlStr += "</Style>";
  xmlStr += "</Styles>";

  xmlStr += '<Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">';

  xmlStr += "<Table>";

  xmlStr += "<Row>";
 
  xmlStr += '<Cell ss:StyleID="cellWithBorders"><Data ss:Type="String">Client Name</Data></Cell>';
  xmlStr += '<Cell ss:StyleID="cellWithBorders"><Data ss:Type="String">Entity</Data></Cell>';
  
  xmlStr += '<Cell ss:StyleID="cellWithBorders"><Data ss:Type="String">Country</Data></Cell>';
  xmlStr += "</Row>";
```